# What are those many '@' characters seen in a log file from vim?

Tags: vim

I have one log file, there are many `@` characters in it when viewing with vim 7.4.160 on centos. But no matter `cat` or `cat -A` doesn't show these characters.

Those `@` characters are at the beginning of some empty lines(which are in fact no real lines, because vim doesn't give them line numbers.) When i use key `j` or `k` to move between them, the cursor will just move like those lines are not there.

I doubt whether it is some file hole there, or vim's typesetting.

The

```
[INFO 2016-07-05 18:26:08 xxxx] xxx
@
@
@
[INFO 2016-07-05 18:26:08 xxxx] xxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `:help window-contents`:

```
If the last line in a window doesn't fit, Vim will indicate this with a '@' in
the first column of the last lines in the window, like this:

    +-----------------------+
    |first line             |
    |second line            |
    |@                      |
    |@                      |
    +-----------------------+

Thus the '@' lines indicate that there is a line that doesn't fit in the
window.
```

You can play with `:help 'display'` if you don't want those `@`s.

Answer (score 0):

These characters indicate that there are more content in the file below the screen.